# Adding multidict values to a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, pyramid

I am sending data from an HTML form, and I handle it with python(Pyramid framework), this is what I have in my view:

```
 @view_config(renderer='json', request_method='POST')
    def modify(self):
        d = self.request.params
        if d.get("perms"):
            if type(d.get("perms")) == str or type(d.get("perms")) == unicode:
                d["perms"] = [d["perms"]]
            for perm in d["perms"]:
                d[perm] = "on"
```

When I try to do `d["perms"] = [d["perms"]]`, I get an error:

```
KeyError: 'NestedMultiDict objects are read-only'
```

I have tried to change the above piece of code to:

```
perms = []
for k, v in d.iteritems():
    if k == "perms":
        if type(v) == str or type(v) == unicode:
            perms = [v]
        for perm in perms:
            d[perm] = "on"
```

But it gives me the same error.

Is it possible to add a `MultiDict` value to a list? 
If so, how?
Why is a `MultiDict` read-only?

Comment: The error is still happening on the line `d[perm] = "on"` (and putting it in a for loop instead of an if statement doesn't make any difference). What are you trying to do? From the original code it looks like you're trying to change the `d` dictionary, which as it notes isn't possible. What are you trying to do in the new code?

Comment: Try to copy the read-only dictionary like `dd = d.copy()`  and see if you can modify `dd` as d is readonly. Also you could check type with `isinstance(v, basestring)`

Comment: @DavidRobinson on my form I have permissions that could be turned on and off. On creation of a permission, I select the permissions I want `on` I am trying to turn the permissions `on`, which has been selected. I originally got a `request.json_body`, but that just stopped working, so I had to change it. In the new code I am trying to put the values in `perms` into a list...

Comment: @sagarchalise Thanks your idea worked `:)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to do what you're doing :) Just use `request.getall('perm')`, which will always return a list.

> Several attributes of a WebOb request are “multidict”; structures
>   (such as request.GET, request.POST, and request.params). A multidict
>   is a dictionary where a key can have multiple values. The
>   quintessential example is a query string like ?pref=red&pref=blue; the
>   pref variable has two values: red and blue.
>
> In a multidict, when you do request.GET['pref'] you’ll get back only
>   'blue' (the last value of pref). Sometimes returning a string, and
>   sometimes returning a list, is the cause of frequent exceptions. If
>   you want all the values back, use request.GET.getall('pref'). If you
>   want to be sure there is one and only one value, use
>   request.GET.getone('pref'), which will raise an exception if there is
>   zero or more than one value for pref.

http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/webob.html

(you should also not try to modify the values of `request.params`, which is read-only. Use a separate dict instead.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it was somewhat useful, but I ended up just making a copy of `d`